# Cannot display counts in a tibble in R

Tags: r, count, tibble

I have a tibble

> ## A tibble: 32,091 x 9

I would like to display the counts of this tibble

```
class %>% count(class$segment)
```

However, it is giving me the error below:

> Error in parse(text = x) : :1:10: unexpected symbol

Can you please help me?

Extra info:

```
library(dplyr)
class %>% 
     count(segment)
```

> > class
> >
> > ## A tibble: 105,396 x 9    customer_id segment rfm_score transaction_cou~ recency_days amount recency_score frequency_score
>
> ```
>      <int> <chr>       <dbl>            <dbl>        <dbl>  <dbl>         <int>           <int>  1          28 Freque~       551
> ```
>
> 1000            0 3.76e3             5               5

Comment: Don't use `class$` in dplyr verbs. `class %>% count(segment)`.

Comment: Are you sure the error came from that code and not somewhere else? Although as r2evans mentioned you don't need the `class$`, it should also work fine as you've written it (well, output names will be wonky, but this shouldn't produce an error). If you just run the line `count` with nothing else, does the output say "namespace:dplyr" at the bottom?

Answer (score 1):

`count` take the unquoted column name

```
library(dplyr)
class %>% 
     count(segment)
```

Comment: > library(dplyr)
> class %>% 
+     count(segment)
Error in count(., segment) : object 'segment' not found

Comment: > class
# A tibble: 105,396 x 9
   customer_id segment rfm_score transaction_cou~ recency_days amount recency_score frequency_score
         <int> <chr>       <dbl>            <dbl>        <dbl>  <dbl>         <int>           <int>
 1          28 Freque~       551             1285            0 3.76e3             5               5